# redux is not importing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

unsure what the error means, I'm importing redux like I would anything else

first time using Redux following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDJ2eidE-b0&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwiaOAuTtVXittwybYIorRB3&index=7&ab_channel=Codevolution

code so far up to around 7:00

```js
import redux from "redux";
const redux = require("redux")

const createStore = redux.legacy_createStore

//Action - action property
const CAKE_ORDERED = "CAKE_ORDERED"

//orderCake = action creator
function orderCake() {
    return {
        type: CAKE_ORDERED,
        quantity: 1
    }
}

//state
const initialState = {
    numOfCakes: 10,
}

//(prevState, action) => newState
//reducer - updates state - returns new state of application
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CAKE_ORDERED:
            return {
                numOfCakes: state.numOfCakes - 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer)
console.log("initial state", store.getState())

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => console.log("update state ", store.getState()))

store.dispatch(orderCake())
store.dispatch(orderCake())
store.dispatch(orderCake())

unsubscribe()
```

I get this error:

> import redux from "redux";
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

expecting redux to be imported

Comment: oh it's supposed to be "import redux from redux" as error but it wont let me edit again..

Comment: Did you try removing `import redux from "redux";` and only keeping `const redux = require("redux")` It should work then I would presume.